# Discord.py bot crate function gives error

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I want a bot to give 1 in 25 registered users who talk to get a crate, which has 5 coins.

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    primary_id = ctx.message.author.id
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        print("")
    else:
        bob = random.randint(1,25)
        if bob == 1:
             await bot.say("You got a crate! It contained 5 coins!")
             amounts[primary_id] += 5
             with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
                json.dump(amounts, f)
        else:
           print("")
```

Error whenever I type something:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zorin/Desktop/den.py", line 68, in on_message
    id = ctx.message.author.id
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Answer (score 2):

[`on_message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) takes a [`Message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object, not a `Context` object.

You should probably also add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to the end of your `on_message` coroutine. [Otherwise none of your commands will be called](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

[`bot.say` will not work outside a command](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-bot-say-in-other-places-aside-from-commands).  Use `bot.send_message` instead.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    primary_id = message.author.id
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        print("")
    else:
        bob = random.randint(1,25)
        if bob == 1:
             await bot.send_message(message.channel, "You got a crate! It contained 5 coins!")
             amounts[primary_id] += 5
             with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
                json.dump(amounts, f)
        else:
           print("")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Im confused on how to put all of this into my code?